# Accessing Couchbase instance via Javascript (not Node.js)

Tags: javascript, couchbase, qooxdoo

I am looking to be able to access a Couchbase instance via Javascript.  My intent is to use Couchbase as the backend for a Qooxdoo JSON datastore.  I understand that Couchbase has a RESTful interface but, eventually, I'll need to wrap security and some other functions, so I'm guessing that a direct connection will not meet my requirements.

So, my question is, what would be the best way to do this?  Sounds like a proxy server built around an existing Couchbase client is the way to go, but I'm open to suggestions.  I'm looking for light-weight and fast.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you already found it, but anyway :) ... considering the qooxdoo REST part, here's the [REST manual page](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.5/pages/communication/rest.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nginx module built which allows to access couchbase over HTTP http://labs.couchbase.com/couchbase-nginx-module/

So you can expose your storage and use authentication schemes provided by other nginx modules.

Oh, and also there is REST wrapper written in ruby https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-rest-api-rails

Comment: Thanks, I think nginx will be the way to go.